# Why $a^H\text{diag}(bb^H)a=b^H\text{diag}(aa^H)b, a, b\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1}$

Tags: matrices

Lately, I am readig a paper titled
[Aperture-Level Simultaneous Transmit and Receive With Digital Phased Arrays](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8964414).

In it, it is mentioned:
[Here is the link to the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyHOK.png)

Basically, the author uses $\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{bb}^H)\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{aa}^H)\mathbf{b}, \ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1}$ to transform $P_n=\mathbf{b}_{r}^H\mathbf{M}_{br}b_r$ into $P_n=\mathbf{b}_t^H\mathbf{M}_{bt}\mathbf{b}_t$, where $\mathbf{b}_t, \mathbf{b}_r \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1}, \mathbf{M}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}, \eta_r, \eta_t, \sigma_r^2, P_t$ are known scalars, $(\ \cdot\ )^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

My first problem is, I don't know why $\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{bb}^H)\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{aa}^H)\mathbf{b}, \ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1}$.

Second, if it is right, I can't figure out why the third term $\mathbf{diag}[\mathbf{M}\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{b}_t\mathbf{b}_t^H)\mathbf{M}^H]$ can be transformed into $\mathbf{diag}[\mathbf{M}^H\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{b}_r\mathbf{b}_r^H)\mathbf{M}]$

Comment: Let $(x,y) = \sum x_i\bar{y_i}$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb C$. Your expression is simply $(a,a)(b,b) = \sum |a_i|^2 \sum |b_i|^2$ which is symmetric in $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{diag}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_ie_i^H A e_ie_i^H$, where $e_i$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb C^N$.

Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
a^H \text{diag}\left(bb^H\right) a 
&= \sum_{i=1}^N a^H e_ie_i^H bb^He_i e_i^Ha \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^N b^He_i e_i^Haa^H e_ie_i^H b \\
&= b^H \text{diag}\left(aa^H\right) b. 
\end{align}
$$